# how to login by username and password for getting token_id and access_token using postman in auth0?

Tags: auth0

When I am trying to login with username and password to get token_id and access_token using postman with auth0 by installed using Postman Collection in Postman

I get an error in login method of database:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the `/oauth/ro` endpoint is being deprecated. You should be making a call to `/oauth/token` instead.

Comment: yup i know that oauth community working on it to update that endpoint,  /oauth/token end point does not return id_token

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

Try to send the first request with login/password by standard authentication (Authorization tab > Type > Basic Auth).

As the following steps I recommend to check the relevant Postman manual: [Using the Auth0 API with our Postman Collections](https://auth0.com/docs/api/postman) and use the predefined collections from [Auth0 API Documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api/info) (press on "Run in Postman" button).

In addition, it's strongly recommended to use the [Native Postman app](https://www.getpostman.com/apps), but not its deprecated Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the `id_token` by using the `/oauth/token` endpoint, and passing `scope=offline_access`. Here is an example of my POST payload (Python code):

```
{
            "grant_type": "http://auth0.com/oauth/grant-type/password-realm",
            "scope": "offline_access",
            "client_id": client_id,
            "client_secret": client_secret,
            "username": username,
            "password": password,
            "realm": database_connection,
}
```

Response:

```
{
    access_token: "lK...",
    expires_in: 1000,
    id_token: "eyJ...",
​    refresh_token: "ym...",
}
```